# How to choose the file name when user uses "save as"?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, http-headers, content-disposition

I have implemented a basic file upload/download on top of AppEngine datastore.
The functionality that I want is that a file named "base.c" will be opened as a text file.
so I did the following:
(of course my code is for a general case but this specific example illustrates the problem)

```
resp.setContentType("text/plain");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=base.c");
```

This opens it as a text file in the browser which is just what I needed.
But I also want that when the user uses the browser's "save page as.." option it will offer the initial name of "base.c". **It does just that in firefox**(6) but it gives the default name of "download" on chrome(15) and safari(5).
Even worse - when choosing base.c as the file name chrome warns the user that this is the wrong extension and asks for confirmation to continue.
Now if I use "attachment" instead of "inline" it does not open the file but download it with the **right** name.

What can I do to make the default save as.. name be "base.c"?
Is this the browser's fault or am I misusing the HTTP headers?

(if it is any help, all test were on OSX 10.6 and the download site is of the sort:
http://------.appspot.com/download?name=base.c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue; see http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#inlwithasciifilename -- only FF gets this right.

Answer (score 3):

I think most browsers default the page name as the current page for the save as option.

One option may be to change the URL from appspot/download?name=base.c to appspot.com/download/base.c by making use of the url-pattern in web.xml.

e.g.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>download</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/download/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then parse the URL to get the filename from the datastore.

I apologize if this won't work with GAE, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: There is no actual static file on the filesystem. It is outputted by the servlet from the datastore.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with GAE. Have you tried using the url-pattern in the web.xml config? I have edited my answer

Comment: @Danish: this must work. You just need to get the filename by `request.getPathInfo().substring(1)` instead of `request.getParameter("name")`. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html.

Comment: It go me almost to the right place, but now the default file name is "base" (and gets saved as base.txt)

Comment: @Danish - Can you try commenting out the content-disposition header to see if that works since you aren't forcing a save as?

Comment: @scott Didn't make a difference. Still tries to save as "base".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an actual answer but this might solve your problem. you can give the user the option to choose between a preview and a download. this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expect the `filename` argument to `Content-Disposition` to be respected for any value other than `attachment`. Your best option, as @scott suggests, is to modify your URL mapping so that the URL path ends with the filename you want; this is also friendlier for users. Another option you could use in conjunction would be to show the file formatted inside an HTML page, with a 'raw' download link that sends `Content-Disposition: attachment`, just like GitHub does.